# localSettings cast exception

Tags: casting, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I try to check if the Setting "tournament" is already set and if not then set the default to 4.
But when I run this it crashes with an exception: Platform::InvalidCastException ^

Where is the invalid cast?

```
ApplicationDataCompositeValue^ tournament_composite = safe_cast<ApplicationDataCompositeValue^>(localSettings->Values->Lookup("tournament"));

if (tournament_composite == nullptr)
{
    values->Insert("tournament", dynamic_cast<PropertyValue^>(PropertyValue::CreateInt32(4)));
}
else
{
    int tournament = safe_cast<IPropertyValue^>(tournament_composite->Lookup("tournament"))->GetInt32();
    switch (tournament)
    {
    case 0:
        lb_tournament->SelectedIndex = 4;
        break;
    case 3:
        lb_tournament->SelectedIndex = 0;
        break;
    case 5:
        lb_tournament->SelectedIndex = 1;
        break;
    case 7:
        lb_tournament->SelectedIndex = 2;
        break;
    case 11:
        lb_tournament->SelectedIndex = 3;
        break;
    default:
        lb_tournament->SelectedIndex = 4;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently, some `safe_cast` cast is failing.  Only you have the power to find out which one.  Use the debugger, Luke.  Which cast is failing?  What is the actual type of the object that you are trying to cast?  How did the program get to be in that state?  On the Debug menu, click Exceptions and check the C++ Exceptions box.  You'll very quickly see where the problem is occurring.

Comment: What is the relation of `values` and `tournament_composite->Values`?  If `tournament_composite` is `nullptr`, then you insert a PropertyValue into `values` with the key `tournament`.  Otherwise you're looking up `tournament` in `tournament_composite->Values`.  So the place you're inserting your default value is not the same place you're reading it from.